# Jpa/Hibernate Thrown Exception is not Informative

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have searched for answer but could not find any useful information on this.

So I am working on a Spring Boot project with Hibernate as orm.
When an exception occurs on persistence layer Hibernate does not give much details about exception.

For example if DataIntegrityViolationException(string variable too long) occurs it does not tell which field caused this exception.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:
Added code snippets as asked.
This field gives error since uri may exceed 255 characters.But it does not tell anything about the entity or field of entity that caused the exception.I have made some effort to find the problem.

```java
@Convert(converter = URIConverter.class)
@Column(unique = true, updatable = false,nullable = false)
private URI fileUri;
```

```java
@Component
public class URIConverter implements AttributeConverter<URI, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(URI uri) {
        return (null == uri) ? null : uri.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public URI convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
        return (null == s || s.isEmpty()) ? null : URI.create(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: This exception comes from the Database and cannot be better as the string the database returns.

Comment: I think that your piece of code would ease the efforts to answer.